# How to remove ribbon line from ggplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like my caption to be in colored lines (as in "Estrato", from above), but also with colored background (as in "strat"). That is, unite the two. I tried to put colour = NA to remove the ribbon line but the background disappeared from the legend.

```
ggplot(h, aes(x=p, y=r, color=strat, fill=strat))+
      geom_line() +
      geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=r-sd, ymax=r+sd), alpha = 0.2,colour=NA)+
      theme_bw(16)+
      theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=10),legend.text=element_text(size=10),
            axis.text.x= element_text(size=10), axis.title.x=element_text(size=12),
            axis.title.y=element_text(size=12), legend.title = element_text(size=12))+
      xlab("\nParcelas")+
      ylab("Riqueza\n")+
      labs(colour = "Estrato")
```

[image]

Comment: To unite the legends, both aesthetics must have the same label: `labs(colour = "Estrato", fill="Estrato")`

Answer (score 2):

If you set two different aesthetics to link to the same column in your dataset, `ggplot` will try to combine the legends, but that link will be broken if you change any element of the legend of one without adjusting the other.  This means that you need to also address the `fill=` legend if you are changing the title of your `colour=` legend:

```
labs(colour = "Estrato", fill = "Estrato")
```

To explain why, here's a sample dataset and plot:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  x=rep(1:10,4),
  y=c(rnorm(10,0,0.05), rnorm(10,0.05,0.01),rnorm(10,-0.15,0.05),rnorm(10,0.2,0.05)),
  type=c(rep('A',10),rep('B',10),rep('C',10),rep('D',10))
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, color=type, fill=type)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=y-0.02, ymax=y+0.02),alpha=0.2, color=NA)
p
```

[image]

You can see in the above plot that both `fill=` and `color=` are linked to `df$type`, and the legend created combines those two.  However, there are still two legends, but both are combined.  If you think of it this way, then that means when you change the title of one, it will now force `ggplot` to separate the legends:

```
p + labs(color='My_colors')
```

[image]

The solution is pretty simple: just make the same change to both legends.

```
p + labs(color='My_colors', fill='My_colors')
```

[image]

By the way, this also holds true for other adjustments to the legend, like with labels.  So that means if you make changes using `scale_color_manual()`, you'll probably need a `scale_fill_manual()` to put them back together.